# Index all ERC721 & ERC1155 Contracts Deployed on Mainnet

Tags: go-ethereum, nft, erc-721, ethers.js, erc-1155

I am looking to index all ERC721 and ERC1155 contracts on the blockchain into MongoDB. I do not want to use OpenSea's API and would prefer to fetch all this information directly from the chain.

I've figured out how to detect on a block-by-block basis, which transactions are contract deployments, and by calling the supportsInterface method I can also find out if the contract adheres to the ERC721 or ERC1155 standard.

Is there something I'm missing or would this be the best approach?

```
const handleError = () => {
    return undefined;
}

const getContractMetadata = async (address) => {
    const abi = [
        'function name() view returns (string name)',
        'function symbol() view returns (string symbol)',
        'function supportsInterface(bytes4 interfaceId) view returns (bool)',
    ];
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(address, abi, provider);
    const [name, symbol, isERC721, isERC1155] = await Promise.all([
        contract.name().catch(handleError),
        contract.symbol().catch(handleError),
        contract.supportsInterface('0x80ac58cd').catch(handleError),
        contract.supportsInterface('0xd9b67a26').catch(handleError),
    ]);
    return { name, symbol, isERC721, isERC1155 };
}

(async() => {
    await mongoClient.connect()
    const db = mongoClient.db('nft')
    const collection = db.collection('collections')

    let blockNumber = 9193266

    while(true) {
        console.log(`Getting block ${blockNumber}'s transactions`)

        let block = await provider.getBlockWithTransactions(blockNumber++)
        let contracts = block.transactions.filter(tx => Boolean(tx.creates))

        if (contracts.length) {
            console.log(`${contracts.length} contract deployments found in ${block.transactions.length} transactions`)

            for (const contract of contracts) {
                let metadata = await getContractMetadata(contract.creates)
                if (metadata.isERC721 || metadata.isERC1155) {
                    let interface = metadata.isERC721 ? 'ERC721' : 'ERC1155'
                    console.log(`Inserting ${interface} contract ${contract.creates} - ${metadata.name} (${metadata.symbol})`)

                    await collection.updateOne({
                        '_id': contract.creates
                    }, { $set: {
                        '_id': contract.creates,
                        creator: contract.from,
                        blockNumber: contract.blockNumber,
                        blockTimestamp: block.timestamp,
                        ...metadata
                    } }, { upsert: true });
                }
            }
        } else {
            console.log(`No contract deployments found in ${block.transactions.length} transactions`)
        }

        let currentBlockNumber = await provider.getBlockNumber()
        if (currentBlockNumber <= blockNumber) {
            break
        }
    }

    await mongoClient.close()
})()
```

Comment: There are a few contracts that predates the standars final draft some of them may not be fully compliant. CryptoKitties and CryptoPunks are the most famous.

Comment: hi @vivekmanglani please follow up, you have an answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly the idea. Each created contract. And ERC-165.

The implementation is a little deficient.

I'm not sure where `tx.creates` is documented. Hmm.

But in general, please note that any transaction is possible to create MULTIPLE contracts. So that approach will not get all of them.

Also note it is possible to deploy a contract in a normal message call (i.e. not a contract deployment) transaction.